# What's the easiest way to deploy a telegram bot on the web?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to create a telegram bot using [telepot api](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot). I can run locally [this example](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/blob/master/examples/diceyclock.py). What's the easiest and quickest way to make it running somewhere in the web to have my bot working 24/7?

UPD:

The easiest way for me is pythonanywhere:
1. Upload script
2. install dependencies using regular "pip install package_name" from bash console.
3. run script from bash using "python script.py"
4. That's it

Comment: I don't know enough about this tech to say for sure, but this seems too broad and too subjective ("what's the quickest way"). I'd suggest taking a look at the help centre and rephrasing your question to fit SO's guidlines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bunch of cloud hostings with free plans with `python` support:

1. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)
2. [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/)
3. [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/)
4. [Pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)
5. etc

Comment: A few things (note: decent answer to a question that's too broad and subjective, imo). #5 is not an answer. This is also just a link-only answer, which is discouraged. Summaries? Is there an underlying concept maybe?

Comment: Eh alright I guess that sentence helps :)

Comment: @en_Knight good point :D